# Sorting and limiting on spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Say I have a repository of *cats* with *weight* property, if I wanted to find the heaviest cat I have to do this:

```
Page<Cat> cats = catRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 1, Sort.Direction.DESC), "weight");
Iterator<Cat> it = cats.iterator();
if(cats.hasNext()) {
  Cat heaviest = it.next();
} else {
}
```

Trying to simply put `Cat findOneOrderByWeightDesc()` on the repository interface isn't supported.

Is there any simpler way to achieve this on spring data jpa?

---

Edit 5 July 2014: Thomas Darimont has kindly implemented a new feature that solves the problem above: http://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-516

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Cat> findAllByOrderByWeightDesc();
```

should work fine.

Comment: Ah I see... that wasn't quite what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you could use a native query:

This should work with every database:

```
@Query(value = "select a.* from #{#entityName} a LEFT JOIN #{#entityName} b ON a.id = b.id AND a.weight < b.weight WHERE b.id IS NULL", nativeQuery = true)
Iterable<Cat> findHeaviestCat1();
```

Here is an mysql specific variant:

```
@Query(value = "select a.* from #{#entityName} a LEFT JOIN #{#entityName} b ON a.id = b.id AND a.weight < b.weight WHERE b.id IS NULL limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
Cat findHeaviestCat2();
```

Comment: That doesn't look efficient as the query I'm looking for is `select * from cat order by weight desc limit 1`. Limit keyword isn't supported in jpql as it uses `setMaxResult()` instead, but I don't know how to suggest that to spring data jpa

Comment: Ok, you are right in this case - but if you would write this as @Query(value="select ... limit 1", nativeQuery=true) it should work fine, but then you are tied to mysql. Btw. the join variant is more flexible in cases where you want to look for the heaviest cat of a certain "breed", which was of course not what you wanted :)

Comment: FYI I filed https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-516 to track this as a new feature for Spring Data Commons for the next release train Evans.